# .NET: NpgsqlCommand to IQueryable

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core, npgsql

Is there a way to create an IQueryable from an NpgsqlCommand?

Something like this:

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT o.Id, o.Name FROM schema.blogs", connection))

            var blogsQueryable = cmd.Execute<IQueryable<BlogViewModel>>;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Npgsql on its own is just an ADO.NET provider, and as such does not map rows to your own objects.

You should take a look at [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) for a full O/RM, or at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) for a lighter solution.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at Dapper but it doesn’t seem to support a IQueryable result

Comment: If you want IQueryable (i.e. translating LINQ expressions to SQL) then take a look at Entity Framework Core

Comment: Is there something in between? I would like something light like Dapper but with the extensibility of an IQueryable object.

Comment: There's nothing light about the idea of using an IQueryable to access a database - make sure you understand exactly what you're asking for... It means having a component that knows how to translate complex LINQ expressions to SQL, which is exactly what EF Core does.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to make queries. That's why a simple SqlConnection appealed to me.

Comment: Either you write your own SQL, and then you just need Npgsql (or Dapper), or someone else writes your SQL based on an IQueryable expression, and then you need something like EF Core